# Eslint import and export errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I configured eslint in the project but it is pointing import and export errors.
[image]

I added the plugin config:

```
"plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
    "@typescript-eslint/tslint"
 ]
```

but it is generating the error " **Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint/tslint' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'tslint'**"

In the devDependencies was added:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^4.5.0"
```

how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it was executed the command: **./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init** and then reconfigure the eslint.

Installed:

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.5.0
@typescript-eslint/parser@4.5.0
```

Doc: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding tslint to your dependencies in package.json?

Comment: Yes, I added "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0"  and "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^4.5.0" on devDependencies.